# Persistence of ActiveMQ Blob Messages

Tags: java, persistence, activemq-classic

[image]
When we communicating using text if remote server failed or down embedded server will save data in localdb(KahaDB) and send it later. But while sending Blob messages how can we ensure persistence. Here we have to specify upload URL to upload data. This upload URL is accessible to both producer and consumer. In my case my upload URL is in remote. If i send data while network failure then producer will failed to upload(Then how we can persist that message -I think KahaDB can't be used for blob messages).

**"Persistence of Blob Messaging in ActiveMQ"?**

**"Can't we use Database(KahaDB) to Blob Message URL?"**

**"Can We create File Server in embedded broker like in remote activemq server?"**

Answer (score 2):

KahaDB does not store the Blob portion of the BlobMessage.  If you send a message with the URL where the blob is and that resource goes down your receiver won't have access to it, at least not until that resource comes back online.

Comment: is there any possibilities to ensure persistense

Comment: because upload url should be in cloud. When network fails we don't have a storing mechanism.